# How big a war file should be?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, war, grails-2.2

Tomcat 7 manager limit the war file size to 50 Mo.

- Why this limitation of 50 Mo ?
- What should be the maximum war file size ? (in practice)

I'm working with Grails 2.2 which generate a minimal WAR of 28 Mo.
So, the limit of 50 Min is very easy to reach.

Answer (score 27):

This is only a limit set for you to upload and deploy via the Tomcat 7 manager. There really is not a limit on the size of the war file you can deploy to a tomcat server.

[Here](http://maxrohde.com/2011/04/27/large-war-file-cannot-be-deployed-in-tomcat-7/) is a link that can help you increase this upload size.

Quoted from link --

> Go to the web.xml of the manager application (for instance it could be
>   under /tomcat7/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml. Increase the
>   max-file-size and max-request-size:

```
<!– 50MB max –>

 <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>

 <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>

 <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>

 </multipart-config>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Tomcat 8, the `max-file-size` is not in `web.xml` anymore. Instead, open `conf/server.xml` and find the tag entry for the HTTP connector. Then add the

```
maxPostSize="0"
```

attribute and value to this tag. When you have completed editing the `conf/server.xml` file, save it and restart Apache Tomcat.

Comment: `max-file-size` is still in `web.xml` as of Tomcat 8.0.20, set to 50MB as in Oscar Lopez's answer.

Answer (score 7):

The 50 MB default file size limit is not hard-coded, you can change it in the `web.xml` file of the Manager application of your webapp folder. You'll have to increase the `max-file-size` and `max-request-size`:

```
<!– 50MB max –>
<max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
<max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
<file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
```

Replace the current values with the appropriate values for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the web.xml of the manager application (for instance it could be under `/tomcat7/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

Increase the max-file-size and max-request-size to for example 100Mb

Answer (score -1):

In tomcat7, update the `tomcat7/server.xml`. I  installed tomcat7 in ubuntu so the directory is like below

```
ll /etc/tomcat7/
total 220
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root      4096 Oct  6 18:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 136 root root     12288 Oct  6 16:12 ../
drwxrwxr-x   3 root tomcat7   4096 Sep 23 15:44 Catalina/
-rw-r--r--   1 root tomcat7   6506 Jun 27 12:48 catalina.properties
-rw-r--r--   1 root tomcat7   1394 Jan 25  2014 context.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 root tomcat7   2370 Feb 18  2016 logging.properties
drwxr-xr-x   2 root tomcat7   4096 Sep 23 16:06 policy.d/
-rw-r--r--   1 root tomcat7   6716 Oct  6 18:14 server.xml
-rw-r-----   1 root tomcat7   1607 Sep 23 15:50 tomcat-users.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 root tomcat7 168099 Nov 25  2015 web.xml
```

You would see the connector section in the conf file `etc/tomcat7/server.xml`,

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"/>
```

Stop the tomcat and just add the `maxPostSize` at the end,

```
sudo service tomcat7 stop
```

**Update the connector in the server.xml,**

```
<!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
     and responses are returned. Documentation at :
     Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
     Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
     APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
     Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
-->
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" 
           maxPostSize="57000000"/>
```

Then restart the tomcat.

```
sudo service tomcat7 start
```